# Is the RandomX only algorithm to go?

Tags: mining, algorithm, pool-mining

I'm bit lost with some of many stuff around the mining. I'm using xmrig to mine monero with rx/0.

This is by default.

As far as I was able to understand, the pool has to support algorithm I want to use for mining. Also xmrig has to support it.

But I suppose that I can mine monero with different algorithm also, which would be only xmrig configuration ideally.

Is there any advantage to try different algorithm on regular PC?

Does the minexmr.com support other algorithms such as CryptoNight, NiceHash, ...?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got what I wanted here. For whoever looks for an answer for this as well.

https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/comments/vi5mho/is_the_randomx_only_algorithm_to_go/